# Expanding/contracting columns with browser (ASP.Net)

Tags: asp.net, resize

I'm trying to accomplish something like this (http://picturegroup.com) , where you have images displayed in several columns, but as you resize your browser, columns will (dis)appear so to fit what you can see on the screen.

Any ideas on how can I do this (links, etc)?

Thanks!

PS: Bear in mind that I'm quite a ASP.Net noob

Comment: Have you looked at the site's HTML to see what the browser and see what it is using?  That's my suggestion for a starting point on seeing what it is using as it may or may not be easy with what you are using.

Answer (score 0):

The site uses a css property called float.

Here is a link to a tutorial

http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/